# Подсчет количества строк, не имеющих одинаковых символов

Tags: c++, строки, вектор

Пока не научился решать задачу, когда нужно разбивать строки на слова.
Попытался решить, и как мне кажется, получилось что-то, хотя программа и не работает. Да и код получился сложноватый.

Как можно было бы решить?

Условие:   Пользователь вводит строку(неограниченную) и нужно сосчитать количество слов, не имеющих одинаковых букв, т.е. во всех словах буквы разные. 
В подсчет включаются все слова, буквы которых не встречались ранее в других словах. Повтор букв в том же слове допускается. Пример: я ты мы он они. Ответ: 3 (Я + ты/мы + он/они);

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum = 0, SUM = 0;
    string st, str, strr;
    vector<string> s;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cin >> st;
    s.push_back(st);
}

for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) { 
    str = s[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < str.size(); j++) { 

        for (int a = 0; i < strr.size(); a++) { // Строка со всеми буквами
            if (str[j] != strr[a]) {
                sum++;               
            }
            if (sum == str.size() - 1) {
                SUM++;                   // Количество слов 
                sum = 0;
            }
        }  
    }
        strr += str;
    }  
    cout << endl << endl << SUM ;  
}
```

Comment: Ну тут как минимум вопрос, они должны быть попарно без одинаковых букв или прям уникальные во всем предложении

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev  А я все думал уточнять или нет :))  ("... т.е. во всех словах буквы разные.").  Получается, это может быть просто набор символов, в виде строк( abcv  awfef  greggr )

Comment: @Pups в `abcv` и `awfef` есть буква `a` - уточните, что означает разные буквы во всех словах.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Пример в скобах был на то, что строка может быть в виде набора слов, состоящих из символов. Разные: qwerty uiop asd zxcv - 4 разных слова. В принципе думаю, все поняли, что значат разные символы, что все так зациклились на этом.

Comment: @Pups, уточните. Допустим есть строка из 4-х слов -- `мы вы он она я`. Правильно ли я понимаю, что из них годится только `я`?

Comment: @avp Ну, так-то получается здесь 3 слова:      мы / вы      +      он / она      +      я.         / - или

Comment: @Pups, непонятно вы излагаете свои мысли (наверное это я такой бестолковый). Ладно, напишу прогу так, как я понял эту задачу на уникальность символов.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если ограничиться однобайтными кодировками, то для подсчета повторов символов достаточно таблицы из 256 элементов.

Предполагается, что слово, это та последовательность символов, которую читает `cin >> string` (и подобные потоки).

В результате получаем вот такую программу (при вызове с ключем `-l` она дополнительно печатает список уникальных слов).

Данная версия соответствует первоначальной формулировке задачи в вопросе (по крайней мере я так ее понял):

> Во введенной строке подсчитать количество слов, состоящих из уникальных букв.
>   Т.е. слова в которых есть одинаковые буквы в подсчет не включаются.
>   Если в слове содержится буква, которая была в другом слове, то все
>   такие слова из подсчета исключаются.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

#include <string.h>


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  string s;
  vector<string> v;

  cout << "Enter line with words: ";
  getline(cin, s);
  istringstream in(s);

  // Ограничимся однобайтной кодировкой входных символов
  // Не используйте русские буквы в Linux (они в utf-8 занимают 2 байта)
  struct {
    int cnt,  // счетчик, сколько раз встретилась данная буква
      v_inx;  // индекс слова в `v`, где первый раз появилась данная буква
  } chr_set[256];
  memset (chr_set, 0, sizeof(chr_set));

  string w;
  size_t cur_w = 0;
  // Читаем введенную строку `s` по словам
  while (in >> w) {
    // Запомним слово, оно может быть уделено (инвалидировано)  в дальнейшем,
    // если во новом слове есть те же буквы
    // повтор букв в том же слове инвалидирует также и его
    // Инвалидация осуществляется путем замены первой буквы слова на nil
    v.push_back(w);

    // Основная часть, поиск повторяющихся символов
    // и удаление ранее запомненных слов
    for (size_t i = 0; i < w.size(); i++) {
      // перебор всех букв нового слова
      int ch = w[i] & 0xff;
      size_t n = chr_set[ch].cnt++;
      if (n == 0)                    // Первое появление буквы
        chr_set[ch].v_inx = cur_w;   // запомним индекс слова.
      else {                         // Такая буква уже была
        v[chr_set[ch].v_inx][0] = 0; // инвалидируем ранее запомненное слово,
        v[cur_w][0] = 0;             // а также и текущее слово.
      }
    }
    cur_w++;
  }

  int pri_flag = av[1] && strcmp(av[1], "-l") == 0;
  if (pri_flag)
    cout << "Words with unique characters:\n";
  size_t n_words = 0;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < cur_w; i++) {
    if (v[i][0]) {
      n_words++;
      if (pri_flag)
        cout << v[i] << '\n';
    }
  }

  cout << n_words << "  unique words\n";
}
```

---

**Update-1** (ответы на дополнительные вопросы ТС -- *что значит ...*)

1) `v[chr_set[ch].v_inx][0]` -- это первый символ строки, которая находится в векторе `v` по индексу `chr_set[ch].v_inx`. Массив `chr_set[]` индексируется кодом очередной проверяемой на уникальность буквы -- `ch`. Поле `.v_inx` в нем это индекс слова, запомненного в векторе `v`, в котором первый раз появилась данная буква.

2) `v[cur_w][0]` -- опять же первый символ слова, которое запомнено в векторе `v` с индексом `cur_w` (т.е. это только что прочитанное слово, буквы которого проверяются на уникальность).
Это же и ответ на 6) `v[cur_w][0] = 0;`. Записывая 0 в первый байт хранимой в векторе `v` строки мы инвалидируем текущее слово (нашли в нем букву, которая уже была использована ранее).

3) `size_t n = chr_set[ch].cnt++` -- читаем в переменную `n` текущее значение счетчика буквы `ch` (т.е. сколько раз она уже встречалась) и увеличиваем его на 1.

4) `int pri_flag = av[1] && strcmp(av[1], "-l") == 0;` -- смотрим, задан ли аргумент командной строки при запуске программы (`av[1]`) и только если он задан (т.е. `av[1] != NULL`) вызываем функцию `strcmp()`, которая сравнивает значение первого аргумента со строкой `"-l"` и возвращает 0 в случае их равенства.

5)  `int ch = w[i] & 0xff, ну это решил поискать: 0хff - выделение участка памяти на 8 бит, правильно понял ?` -- не правильно.
Строки в С++ это контейнер для типа `char`. В системах на x86 (типичный десктоп, ноут и т.п.) он знаковый.
`0xFF` это маска, которая при наложении (операцией `&`) на преобразуемое в `int` значение обрезает распространение знакового бита. В противном случае все буквы с кодом больше 127 (т.е. русские буквы в кодировке cp1251) стали бы *отрицательными числами* в переменной `ch`.
Возможно более наглядной была бы запись `int ch = (unsigned char)w[i];`

---

**Update-2** (вариант с подсчетом символов в новой формулировке задачи)

> В подсчет включаются все слова, буквы которых не встречались ранее в
>   других словах. Повтор букв в том же слове допускается.

В этом варианте код элементарный, никаких слов запоминать не нужно.

```
  string s;

  cout << "Enter line with words: ";
  getline(cin, s);
  istringstream in(s);

  int chr_set[256] = {0};
  size_t n_words = 0;

  // Читаем введенную строку `s` по словам
  while (in >> s) {
    int new_word = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) 
      // перебор всех букв нового слова
      if (chr_set[(unsigned char)s[i]]) {
        new_word = 0;
        break;
      }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
      // обновим счетчики букв 
      chr_set[(unsigned char)s[i]]++;

    if (new_word)
      n_words++;
  }

  cout << n_words << "  unique words\n";
```

Comment: Пока что, для меня, этот код выглядит сложным :)

Comment: Что именно не понятно? 1) Идея; 2) алгоритм, воплощающий ее; 3) некоторые конструкции кода, реализующие алгоритм? / Спрашивайте конкретно, попробую объяснить в **Update** ответа

Comment: Конструкции кода. 1) v[chr_set[ch].v_inx][0]    2) v[cur_w][0] ;  Не приходилось встречать подобные конструкции.      3) size_t n = chr_set[ch].cnt++;     4) int pri_flag = av[1] && strcmp(av[1], "-l") == 0;  И эти строки не понимаю.    5)int ch = w[i] & 0xff, ну это решил поискать: 0хff - выделение участка памяти на 8 бит, правильно понял ?     6) v[cur_w][0] = 0; В принципе все.

Comment: если в слове одинаковые буквы, то оно не считается уникальным, даже есть слов с такими буквами больше нет, lol например

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon, код в данном ответе именно такой. Вообще же вам надо дискутировать на эту тему с автором вопроса (для этого разместите свой комментарий под вопросом или его собственным ответом)

Answer (score 1):

Для решения достаточно взять `std::set` - заполняете его вашими словами и в конце просто берете его размер. Так как это бинарное дерево с уникальными значениями - все слова в контейнере будут уникальными

Comment: Не годится. Например, слова `он` и `она` попадут в set, однако в них есть одинаковые буквы.

Comment: @avp правильно ли я понял: максимальный результат может быть не более количества букв в алфавите?

Comment: Это вы у автора спросите. Я понял, что нужно отобрать слова, у которых **все буквы уникальные** (т.е. таких букв больше нет во всех словах из строки). Как на самом деле -- уточняйте.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше добавить элемент в вектор тогда, когда ни один элемент вектора строк не будет иметь одинаковый символ с вводимой строкой.

```
string s;
vector<string> vs;
cin >> s;
vs.push_back(s);
//проверку начинаем со второй строки
while (cin >> s) {
    //пытаемся найти строку, с которым данная строка
    //имеет одинаковый символ
    auto It = std::find_if(vs.begin(), vs.end(), 
        [&s](const string& s1)
        { return s1.find_first_of(s) != s1.npos; });
    //если не найден, добавляем в вектор
    if (It == vs.end()) 
        vs.push_back(s);
}
//нам нужно количество таких строк
cout << vs.size();
```

Comment: imho не совсем правильно. При обнаружении дублирования буквы из нового слова `s` в ранее запомненных в векторе словах нужно   как-то помечать их, как тоже не подходящие (а новое слово тоже добавлять в вектор с той же пометкой). Или вести 2 вектора и искать буквы в обеих -- в первом подходящие  слова, во втором остальные и перебрасывать из первого во второй (конечно, тут можно придумать разные алгоритмы с разными контейнерами)

Comment: @avp, что можно придумать разные алгоритмы,  это аксиома, с которым я согласен всегда, что ни один из них не будет самым лучшим,  соглащусь тоже почти всегда...

Answer (score 0):

Кажется решил сам :) Единственный вопрос, я ввожу текст, но так могу делать до бесконечности и выход осуществляю с помощью ввода "0". Можно ли закончить ввод иначе(наподобие функции getline) ?

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int function(string& st, int& sum, string& str) {
    int s = 0, newsum = sum;
    bool answer = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < st.size(); i++) {       
        for (int j = 0; j < str.size(); j++) { 
            if (st[i] == str[j]) {
                answer = false;
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
    if (answer) {
        newsum++;
    }
    return newsum;
}

int main() {
    string st, str;
    int sum = 0;
    cin >> st;
    str += st;
    while (cin >> st) {
        if (st == "0") {
            break;
        }
        sum = function(st, sum, str); 
        str += st;

    }
    if (sum == 1) {
        sum++;
    }
    cout << endl << sum;
}
```

Comment: Ответ на вопрос -- *`"...Можно ли закончить ввод иначе..."`*. Конечно, да. Введите с клавиатуры `Ctrl-D` (в винде `Ctrl-Z`), означающий "конец файла" (`EOF`) и ввод завершится выходом из цикла `while (cin >> st) { ... }` / Вы уверены, что программа решает задачу, как она описана в вопросе? Допустим, в первом же слове есть повторяющиеся буквы. Ваша программа его воспримет как допустимое и добавит к сумме. И т.п.

Comment: @avp Пишу 2 раз, написал и забыл отправить, ибо паралельно исправлял код :) В общем, программа при выходе с помощью ввода "0", считала правильно, если хотя бы одно слово было уникальное, если все слова были одинаковые, т..к цикл if(с вводом "0") был после подсчета, то она и его считала, поэтому при вводе всех одинаковых слов вывод был "1". Но теперь исправил и программа делает то, что я хотел. Ну и да вопрос и вправду, я поставил неточно, сейчас исправлю.

Comment: мне кажется в уточнении задачи (кстати, в новой формулировке она значительно упрощается) лучше написать -- *"в подсчет включаются все слова, буквы которых не встречались ранее в других словах. Повтор букв в том же слове допускается"* / В такой формулировке ваш ответ ее успешно решает. / Я в своем ответе попозже отвечу на ваши вопросы о непонятных вам конструкциях и уточню формулировку (как я ее понимал ранее)

Comment: Благодарю, добавил.